# Get JSON reponse from Server in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

When I send a request, the server will send a response like this:

```
{
    "id":"YWauEwCUIe",
    "name":"User 1",
    "status":"DONE"
}
```

for doing that, i'm using this code:

```
var client = new RestClient(mServer);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddQueryParameter("action", "GET");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string mResponse = response.Content;

mUser = new JObject();
mUser = JObject.Parse(mResponse); // Error Line
string mStatus = mUser["status"].ToString();
if (mStatus.Equals("DONE")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Status: DONE");
}
```

> Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: Null. Path '', line 1, position 4.'

Comment: Did you do such **obvious** thing like checking what **really** contains `mResponse` ? after code like `mUser = new JObject();
mUser = JObject.Parse(mResponse);` I doubt

Comment: [**obviously real content** of `mResponse` is string `"null"`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vSNfQv) which is valid json but JSON.NET doesn't parse it

Comment: My server throwing `null`. btw Thanks I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my response was `null` cause of a `MySQL` error now it solved.

`PHP` code:

```
<?php
    $Message['id'] = "YWauEwCUIe";
    $Message['name'] = "User 1";
    $Message['status'] = "DONE";
    echo json_encode($Message);
?>
```

and this will show this `result`:

```
{
    "id":"YWauEwCUIe",
    "name":"User 1",
    "status":"DONE"
}
```

and this `C#` code will work:

```
var client = new RestClient(mServer);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddQueryParameter("action", "GET");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string mResponse = response.Content;

mUser = new JObject();
mUser = JObject.Parse(mResponse);
string mStatus = mUser["status"].ToString();
if (mStatus.Equals("DONE")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Status: DONE");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use an extremely popular library NewtonSoft:

Take your response shape you get from the server (assuming that JSON object doesn't change and you have all of the fields) you can generate a response class here: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp

For me it generated this code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        public static Welcome FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Welcome self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
```

Here's the example code I have:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace JsonParse
{
    public partial class Welcome
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        public static Welcome FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(json, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Welcome self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var jsonPayload = "{\"id\":\"YWauEwCUIe\",\"name\":\"User 1\",\"status\":\"DONE\"}";
            var jsonAsObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(jsonPayload);
            Console.WriteLine($"{jsonAsObject.Id} {jsonAsObject.Name} {jsonAsObject.Status}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated ... his response is `"null"` and this code will change nothing

Comment: @Selvin it is relevant if you read this bit (assuming that JSON object doesn't change and you have all of the fields). In your case you didn't.

Comment: Irrelevant... He is already using... Json.net - Newtonsoft.Json.Linq... Again json.Net doesn't parse what he is getting from server.. So you so called answer, doesn't answers the question

Comment: @Selvin a response of { "null" } doesn't match the class it would serialize into ... it's relevant lol

Comment: Lol, his response is null which is pretty valid and fit the type... Moreover, if his server returns right json, guess what, his code is working fine. So again your answer change nothing as the problem was on server side